# Why wouldn't this vector not contain the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

$[x,y,z]^T$ with $x=1$ supposedly doesn't contain the zero vector according to my study guide for my Linear Algebra midterm. I know that for any vector which is itself a vector space that it will contain itself and thus contain the zero vector. But the solution given to me is only "The plane of vectors $[x,y,z]^T$ with $x = 1$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ since it does not contain the zero vector. It fails closure of vector addition and scalar multiplication as well."

Which I've done the tests for a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ myself (by the way it's asking if this is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ just if you're wondering), and to me it looks like I can multiply this vector by $0$, likewise take the negation of itself and get $0$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of confusion in what you said but the bottom line is this: The set of column vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ with first entry $1$ cannot contain the zero vector because the zero vector begins with $0$.

It can also not be closed under addition because the sum of two such vectors begins with $2$ not $1$. It can also not be closed with respect to scalar multiplication by reals because scaling by $2$ makes a 2 in the first position.